# How to write protractor test for aria-hidden

Tags: html, protractor

How to identify whether the aria-hidden attribute is true or not in protractor tests. The place I want to use it is here.

```
<html>
    <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code that you tried and any error messages that you got? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use
`expect(element(by.css('span')).getAttribute('aria-hidden')).toBeTruthy()`